# ggplot2 group creates (non-existant) decimal classes for integer data

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following code produces two plots using mtcars with groups based upon the number of gears (integer data).

Why does the legend should intermediate (.5) classes between the integers?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

result <- mtcars

for(i in 1:2) {
  nam <- paste("p", i, sep = "")
  coln <- colnames(result[i+4])
  assign(
    nam, ggplot(result,aes_(x=~disp,y=as.name(coln), group=~gear, color=~gear)) +
      geom_line() +
      geom_point() +
      scale_colour_distiller(palette = "Dark2", direction=-1, guide="legend") +
      scale_y_continuous(name=coln) +
      scale_x_continuous(name="x")
  )
}


plist <- mget(paste0("p", 1:2))
do.call(grid.arrange, plist)
```

Answer (score 1):

From `?scale_colour_distiller`:

> The distiller scales extends brewer to **continuous** scales by smoothly interpolate 6 colours from any palette to a continuous scale.

Emphasis added.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `gear` is a continuous variable.

Before the `for` loop, add `result$gear <- as.factor(result$gear)`.

You will also need to replace the color scale with a discrete scale such as `scale_color_brewer()`